# Is there any chance of IP getting blocked?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server

I have my dedicated webserver in US I was installed sitemap script and was running the same. but frequently the script was stopped many times. and also parallel I was opened FTP port too. both are from same IP(my ISP IP). doing some trouble shooting and trail and error method I was'nt able to access my server from my ISP IP but able to access from another IP. I enabled all security options in WHM. so what may be the reason why my IP get blocked? how can I regain my access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF your IP is blocked, access the server from other IP address say use a different ISP.

You need to check the logs to see, why the ip is blocked. Most Cpanel servers use the firewall, CSF.

If CSF is installed you can check whether your IP is blocked in CSF, using the command.

```
grep xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /etc/csf/* -irl
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is to be replaced with your ip.

If the output contains any files, you need to remove the ip from those files. If your ip is a static one, you can add it to your allow list using

```
csf -a xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Also you can search /var/log/lfd.log to fing why your ip is being blocked.

```
grep xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /var/log/lfd.log
```

Comment: Thanks ajo...but how do I check the same from WHM or cpanel? as I dont have much knowledge about linux