# Why my IP got blocked from my webserver?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any chance of IP getting blocked??](https://serverfault.com/questions/265177/is-there-any-chance-of-ip-getting-blocked)

I have my dedicated webserver in US I was installed sitemap script and was running the same. but frequently the script was stopped many times. and also parallel I was opened FTP port too. both are from same IP(my ISP IP). doing some trouble shooting and trail and error method I was'nt able to access my server from my ISP IP but able to access from another IP. I enabled all security options in WHM. so what may be the reason why my IP get blocked? how can I regain my access? I rather prefer through WHM or Cpanel as I dont have much knowledge in Linux

Comment: Please do not re-post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Contact your web host.  I could list lots of possible reasons, but all of them end with "Contact your web host and XXXX."